# Phase at which peak of interference pattern occurs after adding 2 sine waves

Tags: python, signal-processing

Given 2 sine waves, I calculate the resultant sine waves by adding them. Now I want to calculate phase at which peaks of the interference pattern occurs.

here is the plot generated by me:
[image]

and here is the image I am trying to create. I want to draw the subplot A:
[image]

Here is the script used by me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w_s = 10*2*np.pi
w_d = 11.5*2*np.pi
a_s = 1
a_d = 1
phi_d = 0

x =np.arange(0,2,0.01)

v_s = [a_s*np.cos(w_s*t) for t in np.arange(0,2,0.01)]
v_d = [a_d*np.cos(w_d*t + phi_d) for t in np.arange(0,2,0.01)]
resultant = [sum(i) for i in zip(v_s, v_d)]

f, (ax1, ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x,resultant,'k')
ax1.set_ylabel('sum')
ax2.plot(x, v_d,'b')
ax2.set_ylabel('dendrite')
ax3.plot(x, v_s,'r')
ax3.set_ylabel('soma')
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in f.axes[:3]], visible=False)
plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Will the amplitudes of the sine waves to be added always be equal? If yes, that simplifies things greatly...

Comment: No, this is just for the generalization. but still how would you proceed if the amplitudes are same.

Comment: With equal amplitude waves, you can get an easy closed expression for the sum, which is given as the product of a rapidly varying sinewave and a slowly varying sine wave (see [ref1](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/audio/sumdif.html)). From there getting the timesteps at which the rapidly varying factor reaches extrema is trivial (and not a programming problem, but a mathematical one). The only thing that puzzles me is the black dots in the figure you've attached: it seems to be the phase (argument) of smt, but that isn't clear. Also, the vertical lines in the figure don't align with

Comment: ... the extrema of the sum. So whoever made that was guessing at those locations or plotting something different from what you're asking. Can you elaborate on what you want to add to the figure other than what you already have? So, I guess the green envelope (easy, see the ref), but what are those black dots?

Comment: green envelope is not the issue....
So basically those black dots refers to value of phase at which the peaks in each resultant(sum) wave appear.

Comment: How do you define the phase of the sum of two sines? Using phasors, the *angle* of the sum, observed at the local maxima of the sum, [doesn't remotely look like that](http://picpaste.com/figure_1-mvEWhGHb.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Hilbert Transform](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) to calculate the *Analytic Signal* and hence the [envelope and instantaneous phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal#Envelope_and_instantaneous_phase):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)

a1, f1, phi1 = 1, 10, 0
a2, f2, phi2 = 1, 11.5, 0
s1 = a1 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f1 * t + phi1)
s2 = a2 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f2 * t + phi2)


fig, (axsum, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(10,8))

axsum.plot(t, s1+s2, 'k')
axsum.set_ylabel("sum")

ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b')
ax1.set_ylabel("signal 1")

ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r')
ax2.set_ylabel("signal 2")
ax2.set_xlabel("time in s")


sum_analytic = signal.hilbert(s1+s2)
axsum.plot(t, np.abs(sum_analytic), 'g', lw=2)
for ix in signal.argrelmax(np.abs(sum_analytic))[0]:
    axsum.axvline(t[ix], color='r', lw=2)
```

[image: envelope of signal]

---

You might want to take a look at a [NumPy tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html), all your list comprehensions weren't necessary, for example.